# ошибка при создании проекта во vue

Tags: vue.js, npm

При создании проекта во vue cli  у меня возникает ошибка в терминале.
Что может быть не так?
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...er-plugin-utils":"^7.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/nekrofil/.npm/_logs/2020-08-17T17_05_34_675Z-debug.log
ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Более подробную информацию про кэш можно посмотреть [тут](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/cache.html)